# Draw a Java christmas tree with tabs and asteriks

Tags: java, tree

I need to draw a java xmas tree with given n numbers of rows, but not how it is commonly being drawn like this:

```
     *
    ***
   *****
  *******
```

but like this, with seperation tabs:

```
             *
         *      *
    *        *      *
*        *       *      *
```

The code I have so far is this:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i =5;                           
        for(;i!=0;i--) {
            for(int j=0; j!=i; j++);        
                System.out.print("\t\t*");
```

I have Finally wrote the code by myself:

```
int x = 5;
        for(int i=1; i<=x; i++)
        {
            for (int k=0; k<x-i; k++)
            {
                System.out.print("\t");
            }
            for (int j=0; j<i; j++)
            {

              System.out.print( "\t*\t" );
            }
                System.out.println("");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You seem to have a typo: ```for(int j=0; j!=i; j--);```. That statement now does nothing.

Comment: @JornVernee "That statement now does nothing" No, the line will insert a long wait unless the optimizer is smart enough.

Comment: You forgot to... ask a question.

Comment: Please include a definition of a "java xmas tree."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This lines up the stars in rows

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    int n = 6;
    int i = 0;
    int pad = 7;
    while (i < n) 
    {

        String star = new String(new char[1 + i *2]).replace("\0", "*\t");
        String space = new String(new char[1 + pad]).replace("\0", "\t");
        System.out.printf(space + star + "\n");
        ++i;
        --pad;
    }

}
```

***EDIT***
This alternates them as per your demo

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final int it = 5;
    int pad = it;
    int i = 0;
    String space;
    while (i < it) {
        String star = new String(new char[i + 1]).replace("\0", "*\t\t");

        space = new String(new char[pad]).replace("\0", "\t");

        System.out.printf(space + star + "\n");
        ++i;

        --pad;

    }

}
```

done with for loops

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    //final int it = 5;
    int size;
    size = 5;

    for( int i = 1;  i < size; ++i)
    {
        String star = "";
        for (int p = size; p > i; --p)
        {
            star += "\t";
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j)
        {
            star += "*\t\t";
        }

        System.out.println(star);


    }

}
```

another solution using only 2 loops

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    //final int it = 5;
    int size;
    size = 5;
    List<String> pad = new ArrayList<String>();
    pad.addAll(Arrays.asList("\t","\t","\t","\t","\t"));
    for( int i = 1;  i < size; ++i)
    {
        String star = "";
        //Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([)|(,)|(])");
        star += pad.toString().replaceAll("\\[|\\]|,", "");
        for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j)
        {
            star += "*\t\t";
        }
        pad.remove(pad.size()-1);
        System.out.println(star);

    }

}
```

Comment: feel free to accept my solution if it doesnt fit your needs let me know

Comment: This does the job exacly as I want! Thanks you.
However I was thinking it is possible to do this only using "for" loops.

Comment: you could do it with a stack of `"\t"` instead of the padding loop and just pop one off after each iteration if using 3 loops is an issue

Comment: more solutions using loops added

Answer (score 1):

If you are thinking of drawing a Christmas tree according to the number of rows, you might be after a Java program as such:

```
int rows = 5;
int i = ((rows-1)*2) + 1;
String pattern = "";
for(int j = 0; j <= (i/2); j++) {
    String spaces = "";
    for (int k = 0; k < ((i/2)-j); k++) {
        spaces += " ";
    }
    pattern += spaces;
    for (int k = 0; k < (i-(((i/2)-j)*2)); k++) {
        pattern += "*";
    }
    pattern += spaces+"\n";
}
System.out.println(pattern);
```

where you adjust the variable rows to adjust the height of the Christmas tree.
I used spaces to indent the tree, tab can be used with relative adjustment in width.
Of course the best way is to use printf but this is probably the most straight forward way in creating the Christmas tree you shown within your first block.

Comment: The code you suggest prints another kind of xmas tree. Please note the way of xmas tree i mentioned in the question.